# Listen to BOOT_COMPLETE_ACTION ,when my application is force stop

Tags: android

Normally i can listen to boot complete action.but when user explicitly force stop my application,and then restarts phone.In this case how can i listen to boot complete action.pls  answer with the piece of code..
Incase of ICS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, unless your user launches your app again.

Comment: i have a link  http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols

Comment: This may help you to launch your app from another application. But if your app is stopped, you can do nothing from "inside" to wake it up.

Comment: Ah, people! Just deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

> Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED 
>   Listened every time device is re-started, and to listen you need to register it along with Manifest.xml or through code

In your application, you have to decide where you want to start listening for Device re-start. after it you have to register for Action_boot_completed.

Sorry i cannot write a code for you, but can only suggest.

Comment: This is generally case..i know it.refer my question once again

Comment: If user force stop your application, then you can't do anything.